# Effect of dK (key vector dimension) in transformers

Tags: neural-networks, transformers, attention

Intuitively speaking, what's the impact of changing the $d_k$ (and $d_{kv}$) for transformers?

My understanding is that each attention head is effectively a lower-dimensional projection of a higher-dimensional representation of the sequence, and each head effectively looks at different subspaces. Hence, more heads lead to a lower $d_{kv}$. Presumably this means that for some tokens the model has to learn how to compress it to such a low dimension that it might not capture all the nuances of that token with respect to others within the larger sentence? Is this the best way to think about this?

Answer (score 1):

Each token of the sentence is embedded into a vector of dimension $d_{model}$. When you do multi-head attention with $n$ heads, ***usually*** the key vector dimension is computed as $d_k = d_{model} // n$. It is done this way so that increasing the number of heads will not increase the parameters of the model so that you can compare different configurations.

If you have too many heads compared to the model dimension $d_{model}$, then your key vector dimension could be too small. Thus, **all of the tokens** will have to be compressed to this low dimensional space, so your model will not perform well. On the other hand, if you have too few heads your model will again not perform well.

Of course, there is some number of heads $n$ for which the model works good, but still each head will project the $d_{model}$-dimensional embeddings into $d_k$-dimensional queries, keys and values, with $d_k < < d_{model}$. Is this a reasonable thing to do?

Well, yes, it is.

Query and key embeddings don’t have to be in the large $d_{model}$-dimensional space, because they are only used to compute the attention score (a single number) between each of the tokens. Thus, a smaller space could easily do the job, and it would prevent the model from overfitting. And value embeddings are concatenated at the end to produce the final output of the layer, building back a $d_{model}$-dimensional embeddings for each token.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We're glad that you are contributing your expertise. However, please refrain from self-promotion in your answers. More information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Comment: @Sycorax Please note that I am not promoting a **for-profit product**. This is just a link to a study material that people reading this really might find useful. I guess if I share **The Illustrated Transformer** or **The Annotated Transformer** all is good. But I found those lacking something that can be found in the link that I shared.

Comment: Profit isn't the concern, self-promotion is. If you feel that a part of your blog post directly answers this question, then please quote it and link to it in your answer. But the self-promotion becomes spammy when *nearly every answer you contribute to Stack Exchange* includes a link to the blog, without any elaboration on what part of the blog post answers the question at hand.

Comment: @Sycorax Could you please explain why you flagged this as spam? I was trying to follow the suggestions given here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way

Comment: The answer is taken from my blog-post. The link was added in case OP (or someone else) wants to read more. Also, given that this is my second answer I feel it is perfectly normal to have **nearly every answer** link the blog.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, the top answer in the link you shared provides a bulleted outline of how to avoid this problem. This is your second answer on CV, but not your second answer on *Stack Exchange*.

Comment: I see you are reading very closely what I write. How about a thumbs-up if you think the answer answers OP's question ?

Comment: How about you agree to abide by site norms on self-promotion first?

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Feel free to read my other answers :) Maybe thumbs-up for the other answers too